# Simple multiplayer rpg - synchronizing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am beginner in networking, but I am trying to create simple prototype of game where 2 or more players can see their movements on map.

I've used node + socket on server side and phaser(js game engine) on client side.

My problem is that if I have a ping or sth i can see that the other player like teleporting himself.

When player move i send event to server with player position:

```
socket.emit('updatePosition', { position: player.position, direction: "down" });
```

Then on server I am broadcasting his position to all others:

```
socket.on('updatePosition', (data) => {
    onlinePlayers[socket.id] = data;

    socket.broadcast.emit('updatePlayers', { id: socket.id, position: onlinePlayers[socket.id].position, direction: onlinePlayers[socket.id].direction });
});
```

And in client i update their positions:

```
socket.on('updatePlayers', (data) => {

        players[data.id].position = data.position;  

});
```

How can I eliminate those teleports?

Comment: I was doing the same thing a few months ago, you would not be able to fully eliminate the teleporting. You can try minimize it by client side smooth animation from point A to the new point B that was broadcasted from server, there is a bit of a delay naturally when your players will send too many move commands to the server as well as if the server itself is not dedicated you will face bandwidth issues. I found point and click to be more stable as it broadcasts less move commands. Also you can try looking into authoritative server systems.

Comment: I just need that feature :/ I will look into authoritative server.  I think about 50 players online,  is it big deal for vps?